Unable to delete duplicate guest user in exchange admin centre
We are unable to email a specific external email address due to the guestmailuser existing twice in our Exchange admin centre > contacts.
The user does not exist in Entra (was deleted by MSFT support) and not searchable in 365 Admin Centre.
I have tried to remove the user using various powershell commands, but it complains about "Dual-Write, Azure AD call was make to keep object in sync between Azure AD & Exchange Online)  (this is environment syncs to local AD with Entra ID Sync). I would like to also note I cannot find this user in local AD either.
As mentioned we have a ticket with MSFT but after 2 weeks of "we are escalating" I have turned to the forums.
Any help is appreciated.

Just wanted to let the folks here know, Microsoft had to be the one to delete the duplicate contacts on their back end, after multiple days of waiting, a systems engineer confirmed it was not something we can do ourselves, and had to be changed by them.
Duplicate contact is now gone, and emails are flowing.

I'm sorry to hear about the trouble you're experiencing with this guestmailuser issue. It sounds quite frustrating, especially after waiting for so long for a resolution from MSFT support.
In many cases, it is more helpful to issue a ticket, but it can be a long wait.
Try the following initial:
Check for Hidden Objects: Sometimes, deleted objects can still be present in hidden states. You can use PowerShell to check for hidden objects and remove them:
Get-User -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object { $_.HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled -eq $true }


Hi @Soki Thanks for the response. I tried the command and it yielded nothing back to me.  I did run this after Connecting to ExchangeOnline & AzureAD, both did nothing after running so I am assuming it did not find anything. Just FYI if i run the Get-User -identity brokenuser@gmail.com it does find both of their "MailUser" accounts, so Get-User does work, just not finding hidden users.
